# How to change until the next character (vim), (with the next character can be a set of many)

Tags: vim

With VIM you can change until an underscore for eg: `ct_`

But is there a way to select multiple characters?

Say for example you may want to change until the first underscore or dash `-`.

Is it possible to do this with vim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need search for that:

```
c/[_-]<CR>    " forward search
c?[_-]<CR>    " backward search
```